# Urls without scheme throw error

Tags: go

I write a proxy and the problem is that some links on websites
don't have scheme for example google:

```
<a class="ab_dropdownlnk" href="//www.google.com/support/websearch/?source=g&amp;hl=en">
```

I fetch the url via Client.Do()
How to resolve such urls in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no scheme then use a sensible default. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    href := "//www.google.com/support/websearch/?source=g&amp;hl=en"
    url, err := url.Parse(href)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if url.Scheme == "" {
        url.Scheme = "http"
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client := http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    websearch, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", websearch)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The missing scheme lets the browser choose the protocol and is handy for sites which offer both
http and https. The browser then chooses which protocol to use depending on how he got to the page.
You can use https or http as a default or act like a browser and choose the protocol you used to
fetch the page.

For example, something like this:

```
for _, parsedLink := range parsedLinks {
    parsedLink.Scheme = requestUrl.Scheme
}
```